# What is the effect of hostname aliases on Java applet cache?

Tags: java, applet

I have two servers with hostnames `comp1` and `comp2`. I also have a floating alias (`master`) that is dynamically mapped to one of the two servers. I am serving the same identical applet from both servers. Clients normally connect to the `master` one, but it is perfectly allowable to connect to either `comp1` or `comp2` directly.

Clients are complaining that they are always having to wait for the applet to load (it is quite large). I thought that once the client downloaded the necessary jars, they would be cached and wouldn't be loaded again. At first I thought the client's plugin was set to not cache, but I think I've found the cause of the problem, although I don't understand it.

1. Connect client to `master` (which is currently pointing to `comp1`) for the first time. Must wait for jars to download. This is expected.
2. Connect client to `master` again. I don't have to wait for the jars to download. This is also expected/desired behavior.
3. Connect client to `comp1`. Must wait for jars to download. I'd rather not have this happen, since it is the same server, but I can understand why, as `comp1` appears to the client as a completely different host.
4. Connect client back to `master`. Again, I must wait for all the jars to download. **This is not what I expected.** The jars should have been downloaded already in steps 1/2.

Using the Java control panel, I can see the resources that are in the cache. It appears to me that the resources are keyed by URL, so I don't know why I'm getting what I do. It seems as though that the two different hostnames for the same server is messing up the client's cache.

I should mention that the `master` hostname isn't just a DNS alias. It is an actual different IP addrress that `comp1/comp2` dynamically bind/unbind to while the application is running.

Can you explain what I am seeing here, or suggest some avenues to investigate?

Comment: (Applets?.. in 2011? Geeez...)

Comment: @road to yamburg - <sigh> I know. It's a long story...

Comment: The question is very interesting though. I suspect it has something to do with security.

Comment: @wolcastle:Is the applet too big?Could it be that due to size, the applet gets flushed (but for some reason the URL is still displayed in the control panel?). If you give more size to the cache in the control panel, do you still observe this behavior?

Comment: @user384706 that is a good point. I will have to check it out and see. I'll let you know.

Comment: Also, you might check if the server does the right thing on a IfModified-query, i.e. if the modification dates and similar things are right.

Comment: @user384706 - The cache size didn't seem to be the problem. I had plenty of space left in the cache and still saw the problem.
@paulo - I'm using Tomcat for my web server. How would I go about checking the IfModified-query - do I need to put wireshark between my client/server and check that way?

Comment: On a slightly different note, did you try to reduce the jar sizes by using for example proguard?

Answer (score 1):

**Avenus to investigate:**

This may well be a consequence of the jar filename - e.g. if it is always downloaded into %TMP%\app.jar, then app.jar will get stomped on each time you visit a server.

**Possible workarounds:**

- Alias the file on the servers, so it can be fetched as master.jar, compN.jar
- Use a 301 or 302 to hint to the browser than only one source jar is used (you may need to sign the jar due to same-origin policies)